# Does a using block create and maintain a reference for the GC?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, using, using-statement

This is mostly for curiosity's sake, as there are better ways of implementing almost any use case I can think of for this construct (in C# and other languages I use regularly, at least), but I recently saw on here a [scoped mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315034/thread-safe-queue-isnt-thread-safe-if-peek-returns-a-reference-even-if-reference) which was a cool concept.

My question is, does the using statement maintain a reference (ie: prevent the GC from running on) to the object it's acting on?

For example, if I were to do:

```
using (new ScopedMutex())
{
// ...
}
```

would the ScopedMutex object maintain its existence to the end of the using block, or could the GC run and dispose of it mid-block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the GC will not dispose it.  A reference to that object is stored in a local variable ([see this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310905/2310958#2310958)). A local variable is considered a GC root and the object will be reachable from it (it needs to be reachable for the `using` block to be able to call `Dispose` on it).

Comment: Oh, I feel silly now, of course it needs a reference for dispose to be called at the end... thanks. :)

Comment: If the object in question is a sealed class, and has a do-nothing `Dispose` method, is there any specification that would forbid the JIT from inlining the "Dispose" to nothingness [as e.g. it would be forbidden from inlining `GC.KeepAlive`]?

Comment: @supercat I doubt it. To GC, `Dispose` is yet another method. `Finalize` (surfaced as destructor in C#) on the other hand is what GC cares about specifically and it does have optimizations for objects lacking explicit destructors.

Answer (score 2):

The C# compiler will implicitly create a variable for you. The using statement would actually be transformed into something like the following when compiled (you can use [Redgate Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to see the exact code for yourself, btw):

```
ScopedMutex scopedMutex1 = new ScopedMutex();
try
{
    // ...
}
finally
{
    scopedMutex1.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not dispose it in mid-block.